# How to adapt a overflow-auto div with a dropdown absolute to fit it’s position to the size of the screen using tailwind or css

Tags: php, css, laravel, tailwind-css, vite

I want to adapt the dropdown box to the same position of the column when I try to scroll on the input

How the issue looks: [Imgur issue video](https://i.imgur.com/xL2e3cA.mp4)

My `div` logic looks like this:

```html
<!-- header div -->
<div>
</div>
<!-- table div -->
<div class="w-full overflow-auto">
  <table>
   <thead></thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <button class="w-full p-2">My custom data eight</button>
         <div class="absolute">
           <!-- Dropdown box content -->
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- footer div -->
<div>
</div>
```

I've try to use `relative`, but the idea of using it doesn't work as I expect.

I would like that it looks like in notion [Imgur notion video example](https://i.imgur.com/HiJQLvo.mp4) where the dropdown `div` position fits to the screen size and the scroll div size.

Comment: Have you tried adding position sticky to the dropdown box content? This should help with making sure the content stays within the viewport.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285). That will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @NickFriesen Yes I tried to use sticky inside my dropdown box `div` but it doesn't work

Comment: @BrettDonald I insert a video of my issue, and a video of what I expect as the final result

Comment: That's a good start, @EmmanuelSierraMorales, but we also need enough of your code to be able to reproduce for ourselves the problem you are experiencing. That means we at least need the relevant CSS in addition to the HTML.